# "settings.gradle (Project Setting)" errore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, project-structure

"settings.gradle (Project Setting)" describe me an mistake in the tool bar project so I double click on it and it's just wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
```

Like on this screenShote

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rslQT.png)

that does not prevent me to run my project but I don't know if it's normal, it doesn't seem to be.

before that a delete my `.idea` directory to solve an other problem and it solved it well but maybe is it related to my mistake.

And I can see my Project Structure anymore like I can't change the API level it's just show me this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nwi2.png)

I'm not really confortable with android studio a start ma project like 3 months ago.. so I hope you can help me

thanks y'all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `settings.gradle` should not contain those lines.

This is what it usually has. Information about app module and project name

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "YourProjectName"
```

For your project i can notice that you should replace with stapsQCM, so

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "stapsQCM"
```

After this rebuild your project.
Also read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#settings-file).